# Adding TimeZone Info to Datetime Object C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, asp.net-core-mvc

I have datetimes stored in SQL Server without any timezone information.  The times are in UTC, but that isn't being stored on the database.  Using entityframework, I would like to know the best approach of adding timezone information or when the best spot would be for adding that.

Can I apply this on the model? Or the API endpoint before being sent to the client?

Comment: There is a Time property of DateTime you can append to the existing datetime object

Comment: Why would you need to add it at all? It suffices to document that all times are UTC, or, when times need to be formatted as strings, to use ISO 8601 and append "Z". If you need to perform calculations on these times and non-UTC times, it's a different matter -- you can use `DateTime.SpecifyKind` to explicitly mark the `DateTime` as `Utc` if it isn't already, and then make a `DateTimeOffset` out of it. Including a time zone, or using `DATETIMEOFFSET` in the DB, only makes sense if you intend on actually recording and/or mixing time zones.

Comment: In this case, timezone information is stored on a users profile, but all datetimes are UTC, but without timezone data. It could be when this database was created, SQL Server was not timezone aware.

Comment: @JeroenMostert it matters because the client is attempting to convert from UTC to a local timezone based upon a users profile. Without timezone data being included, even UTC, the conversion fails.

Comment: Storing time in UTC fits most use cases. After you retrieve the UTC time from DB, you could then convert it to the specific timezone from your user profile.

Comment: Then that seems like an API issue, not a database issue. You can certainly make it so the DB layer coughs up time zones, but it seems much more obvious to return the data with time zone info included before it goes over the wire. How best to do this depends on how you declared your endpoint, but making it return `DateTimeOffset` and converting your `DateTime` before returning it seems like the most obvious approach.

Comment: @TZU - I agree that storing dates in UTC works the best, but prior to 2016 SQL Server didn't allow timezone aware datetimes.  While the datetimes ARE technically UTC, I need to get entityframe to add datetime info to the datetime object.

Comment: @JeroenMostert That is what I am trying to ask about.  As it is, the database doesn't store any dates with time zone information.  Using entityframework, I'd like to use some sort of annotation feature to add at the very least utc timezone information to the datetime object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is a good answer or more of a hack, but this is what I did to accomplish this:

```
foreach(var result in results) {
            if(result.Stops != null) 
                foreach(var stop in result.Stops) {
                    stop.EarliestArrival = DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)stop.EarliestArrival, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                    stop.LatestArrival = DateTime.SpecifyKind((DateTime)stop.LatestArrival, DateTimeKind.Utc);
                }
        }
```